# Can I use iron-session in the new Next 12 _middleware file?

Tags: session, next.js

Like said in the question. I am setting a Next session with the help of iron-session. I would like to get the access to the session in the _middleware file that comes with Next 12.
Is it possible to achieve with some additional configuration ?

Comment: This GH issue might shed some light on how to use `iron-session` in middleware: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/419#issuecomment-983020558.

Comment: It will be supported once this PR gets merged: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/pull/510

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported as of version 6.2.0. Here's the relevant example from the [repo's readme](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session#nextjs-middlewares-usage):

```
// /middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { getIronSession } from "iron-session/edge";

export const middleware = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  const session = await getIronSession(req, res, {
    cookieName: "myapp_cookiename",
    password: "complex_password_at_least_32_characters_long",
    // secure: true should be used in production (HTTPS) but can't be used in development (HTTP)
    cookieOptions: {
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    },
  });

  // do anything with session here:
  const { user } = session;

  // like mutate user:
  // user.something = someOtherThing;
  // or:
  // session.user = someoneElse;

  // uncomment next line to commit changes:
  // await session.save();
  // or maybe you want to destroy session:
  // await session.destroy();

  console.log("from middleware", { user });

  // demo:
  if (user?.admin !== "true") {
    // unauthorized to see pages inside admin/
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/unauthorized', req.url)) // redirect to /unauthorized page
  }

  return res;
};

export const config = {
  matcher: "/admin",
};
```